# Нужно сделать AlarmClock

Tags: android, java

В моем приложении надо реализовать опцию Reminder. Пользователь задает время и каждый день в это время будет звучать определенный сигнал. В notification поле появится напоминание о собыытии. Я перелопатил много исходников, много работающих, но не нашел ни одного решения где программа будет работать даже после того как выключить и включить телефон. Одно такое решение есть тут, но там код не компилиться, вообщем чужой код потемки, но тот код вообще сумерки  http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/remindme/3/#9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно подписаться на Intent [BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED), который будет рассылаться после включения устройства и окончания инициализации необходимых системных сервисов. После получения этого intent'а, восстанавливайте ваши таймеры/AlarmManager'ы/etc.

И да, в AndroidManifest.xml необходимо добавить соответствующий permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

UPD: Кстати, как обнаружилось, в туториале по приведённой вами же ссылке, обо всём этом рассказывается.

Comment: я просто писал другую часть программы, пока не трогал аларм, поэтому задал вопрос. Но благодарю что вы ответили, теперь я могу смело разбираться с тем туториалом. то есть в этот интент BOOT_COMPLETED можно записать какие-то extras, а потом их просто получить.

Comment: Нет, в этот Intent записать ничего нельзя. Этот Intent создаётся системой и вызывается ею же. А для того, чтобы сохранить время, в которое должен сработать будильник, почитайте вот это: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html